# Openshift - missing libs, misc, and php folder when creating app

Tags: php, openshift

I got some problems when creating an openshift app. For the first time I create an app using `rhc app create myapp php-5.3`, the localhost directory has 5 folders (.git, .openshift, libs, misc, php). And for the second time I create another app using `rhc app create myanotherapp php-5.3`, I found that the localhost directory only has 2 folders (.git and .openshift)! The other folders are missing!

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Because I'm new using openshift and still don't understand this to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the March OpenShift Online Release Blog post (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog) about the php document root changes (optional document root), I think that will solve your issues.

Specifically the section titled: Simplified Template Directory (Great for PHP/Python/Perl users)